# EF6 - database name in config

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm looking to set the database name in EF6 through the app.config file (and not using the constructor of the data context). I have the provider and database initializer in the config, but where does the database name go? What's the configuration line look like?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The catalog name in connection string

```
 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="MyContextName" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TheDbName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```